# Can matches in Splatoon 2 end in a tie?

Tags: splatoon-2

In the original Splatoon, it was impossible for matches to end in a tie. If both teams covered the same amount of ground, [Judd would randomly pick one of the two teams as the winner](http://kotaku.com/if-you-tie-a-splatoon-match-bullshit-happens-1708331539).

**Does this still apply in Splatoon 2? Will a winner be randomly decided if the game ends in a tie?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A winner will randomly be chosen, just like in the first Splatoon.**

Comment: This answer is how it works in Turf War. In the ranked game types, a tie is impossible because of how points are awarded during the match. For example: Team A pushes to 55 points in Tower Control. Team B retakes the tower, and pushes it to 55 points themselves before losing it. The game will retract a point from Team B, leaving them at 56 points (1 point disadvantage), because Team A got there first.

Comment: @ArrowCase But if nobody pushes (as in this Turf War case where nobody shot ink), then what?

Answer (score 1):

It is a no. If there is a tie, Team Alpha will win. Team Alpha is randomly given, however in The Shoal you can assign a team to Team Alpha.